# Python post application/x-www-form-urlencoded questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, post

This is my first time use python, i want to know how do i post body like below  thanks.

```
POST /httpTest/cityCountry.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.chilkatsoft.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 25

city=Paris&country=France
```

Comment: If you can install a third-party library, `pip install requests`, then go to the requests home page and skim the QuickStart tutorial (or, ideally, work your way through it), and it’ll show you how to do this, and what to do with the result, a few examples down the page.

Comment: If you can’t use a third-party lib for some reason, you want `urllib.request`, which comes with Python and isn’t *that* much harder, but doesn’t have a nice tutorial, so there’s a good chance you’ll get stuck somewhere and can ask a specific question for help.